# Google Billing problem with handlePurchase

Tags: java, android

this is the first time I ask for help on stackOverflow and successively for a trivial thing. I certainly lack the basics to understand it. How do I get billingClient in handlePurchase(billingClient, purchase)?  Thank you in advance for your reply

```
public class Billing {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> skuList;

    ' COSTRUTTORE'
    public Billing(Context context, List<String> skuList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.skuList = skuList;
    }

    ' INTERFACCIA CALLBACK '
    public interface Callback{
        void onSkuDetailsList(BillingClient billingClient, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList);
        void onResponse(Purchase purchase);
        void onError();
    }

    public void MyPurchase(final Callback callback) {

        PurchasesUpdatedListener purchaseUpdateListener = new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, List<Purchase> purchases) {

                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {

                    for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {

                        callback.onResponse(purchase);
                        handlePurchase(billingClient, purchase);

                    }

                } else {

                    callback.onError();

                }

            }

        };

        final BillingClient billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(context).enablePendingPurchases().setListener(purchaseUpdateListener).build();

        

        

    }

    static void handlePurchase(BillingClient billingClient, Purchase purchase) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Please show your code in github.

Comment: @RanjitVamadevan Please do not advise askers to post their code as a link; questions should be self-contained and not require links to external sites to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Add Billing client at top...

```
public class Billing {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> skuList;
    private Billing client;
```

And replace

```
 final BillingClient billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(context).enablePendingPurchases().setListener(purchaseUpdateListener).build();
```

to

```
billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(context).enablePendingPurchases().setListener(purchaseUpdateListener).build();
```

Now billingClient will be accessible within

```
static void handlePurchase( Purchase purchase) {
  //
  billingClient...
    }
```